# Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity

Tags: docker

I just installed a `docker v18.09.2`.

And as stated in their official doc. I tried running `nginx`.

But I get this error:

```
PS C:\Users\rmali> docker run --detach --publish 8090:80 --name webserver nginx

d2e8a8df30520b2c379787a210d1203d56a3f78b9c38187ae04f20c8ad9f1745

C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint webserver (c58767e17064fffd8d5313a0a2f4ffcd7138c1224524753225873d69d1848136): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:8090:tcp:172.17.0.2:80: input/output error.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this discussion](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1967) also [this](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1752), seems this is because last time the docker did not stop cleanly when you shutdown your computer.

The workaround is:

From docker tray menu select `Restart ...` to restart docker.

Or, another solution: see [this](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2722#issuecomment-464144024):

> This is caused by an incompatibility with Docker and fastboot. You can either make sure you stop all containers before shutting Windows down or you can disable fastboot in Windows' power settings by doing the following:
>
> CTRL+R > "powercfg.cpl" > "Choose what the power buttons do" > "Change settings that are currently unavailable" > Deselect "Turn on fast start-up"
>
> You can also disable fastboot with a single command in powershell if you're comfortable doing so:
>
> Set-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power\' -Name HiberbootEnabled -Value 0